# Importing EML (MIME) files in Outlook programmatically

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010, pst

I have a directory full of email files I want to import into Outlook.

These files *should be*, AFAIK, in RFC822 format. Opening them with Notepad++ shows the following and more plaintext

```
Return-Path: XXX
Received: XXX
Authentication-Results: XXX
X-Message-Status: XXX
X-SID-PRA: XXX
X-SID-Result: XXX
X-AUTH-Result: XXX
X-Message-Delivery: XXX
X-Message-Info: XXXX
Received: from XXX
Received: from XXX
DomainKey-Signature: XXX
```

So I guess they are in plain old format. Now I would like to import them into a PST file in order to index and make them searcheable. I have very poor knowledge of Outlook Interop.

Renaming the untitled files to `.eml` works, I can open them with Outlook 2010. Dragging them into Outlook windows half works: emails are not previewed but I can double-click them. Not all emails get imported (I'm talking about 3000+ messages), and Outlook doesn't ingore damaged files, so either all or none.

I was exploring Outlook interop.

The basic idea is the following: for each text file, import that as email into a given folder.

I have tried to write, but not yet to test, the following code

```
Application outlook = GetApplicationObject();

outlook.Session.AddStore(pstPath);

Store theStore = outlook.Session.Stores.Cast<Store>().FirstOrDefault(store => store.FilePath == pstPath);

if (theStore == null) throw new Exception();

try
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dataDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    Folder folder = (Folder)theStore.GetRootFolder();

    foreach (string file in files.Where(file => file.EndsWith(".eml")))
    {
        //What?


    }
}
finally
{
    //Dispose??
}
```

Where `GetApplicationObject` is copied from another SO answer.

Question: is it possible to create a `MailItem` based on the contents of a file? Or do I have to use an email reader and then create the MailItem field by field? Like the following I was writing...

```
IMail mail = builder.CreateFromEmlFile(file);

MailItem outlookMail = outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
outlookMail.Body = mail.GetBodyAsText();
outlookMail.CC = string.Join("; ", mail.Cc.Select(x => x.Render()));
outlookMail.HTMLBody = mail.GetBodyAsHtml();

if (MimeImportance.High.Equals(mail.Importance))
    outlookMail.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
else if (MimeImportance.Low.Equals(mail.Importance))
    outlookMail.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
else
    outlookMail.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;

outlookMail.Sender=outlook.CreateItem()
```

Library I'm trying is from http://www.limilabs.com/mail

Comment: There is no such thing as "Outlook 2012."  There's 2010 (PC), 2011 (Mac), and 2013 (PC).  Can you please verify the version you're using?

Comment: Sorry. I meant Office 2010

Comment: If Outlook isn't central to your use case, you should find almost any other email application to be less of a pain in the you know what.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using C++ or Delphi, you could use the `IConverterSession` MAPI interface - you can play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) if you click the IConverterSession button.
Otherwise you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) and its [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object - its `Import` method supports MIME format (among a dozen or so other formats).

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  set Msg = Inbox.Items.Add
  Msg.Sent = true
  Msg.Import "C:\Temp\test.eml", 1024
  Msg.Save
```